# Link from an Array Generated UITableViewController to a UITabBarController and displaying the relevant data based on Selection

Tags: json, uitabbarcontroller, uistoryboardsegue

Here is the skinny.  This is my First app that i've ever written from scratch and unfortunately its not a helloWorld app.

I've got an NSDictionary stripped down to NSArray and I've created a UITableView based on the data from there.  My issue is that I'm trying to link this to a  UITabBarController (2 tabs total) and have data on each of those pages load based on the table cell that was selected.

I'm not sure if I can accomplish this with the storyboard or if I need to use nibs.  I don't currently have this array saved into memory of any kind so that may be a prereq.

Any help would be very much appreciated. I can provide code if needed.

This site has been amazingly helpful so far in the construction of this App so far just for searching through questions already answered.  This may be in there too but i haven't found it yet, might not be using the correct wording here though.

Comment: I was able to pull this  by using importing the tab bar controller's .h file and then calling it via self.tabbarcontrollername and then referring to the variable via that method.  Works great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under ViewDidLoad I did something like this.

```
tbcClassName *myTBC = (tbcClassName *)self.tabBarController;
self.variableName = myTBC.variableName;
```

then proceed to utilize the variable you just created.

I found the answer in another thread here but I am unable to locate it.